# what kind of multithreaded protection for this case?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I'm using C++, and I'm using the boost library mutex, recursive_mutex and other synchronization objects.

I often have the following pattern:

- void RebuildAll().  This function makes many internal changes.
- void DoSomethingA().  Do some work using what RebuildAll built.
- void DoSomethingB(). Do some work using what RebuildAll built.
- void DoSomethingC(). Do some work using what RebuildAll built.
- ...

The functions can be called from different threads.  I want to be able to execute DoSomethingA(), DoSomethingB() and DoSomethingC() in parallel.  But when RebuildAll() is called, I need to make sure that the DoSomething functions are not being executed.

Is there anything to help me protect these functions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213332/fastest-multi-reader-single-writer-protection-for-shared-resources-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is often called a [reader-writer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock) lock. The rules for a reader-writer lock are:

- Any number of read locks can be acquired at any given time, presumably by different threads.
- Only one writer can ever acquire the lock and only when all readers are done.
- No readers can acquire the lock while the writer owns it.

In your example, `RebuildAll()` would be a writer and `DoSomethingA()` through `DoSomethingC()` would be readers.

Boost has an implementation of a reader-writer lock called [`boost::shared_mutex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.shared_mutex). This is not yet in the standard library, though.